# How to disable the mouseover effect in networkD3 / d3Network network diagrams (GNU R package)

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I would like to disable the mouseover effect in network diagrams as provided on http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/ (search for 'enlarge').
Even if there is no native option I guess it is possible by using `htmltools` or `htmlwidget` inserting the appropriate javascript functions (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/PandaRider/84b9c096e37334c2a4fd945a66b8ccf9).

Update:
Just noticed that the annoying effect shows up in Chrome not in Edge.

Comment: The d3Network project page that you linked has, at the top, a refererral to a more current project, `http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/` That doesn't likely change your question. It's just an observation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I gonna switch to the newer package. But indeed, the visualizations have the same hover effect. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported "natively", but you can achieve this with `htmlwidgets::onRender`...

for `forceNetwork()`:

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", 
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   Group = "group")

onRender(fn, "function(el,x) { d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseover', null); }")
```

for `diagonalNetwork()` and `radialNetwork()`:

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

URL <- paste0("https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
              "master/JSONdata//flare.json")

Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
Flare$children = Flare$children[1:3]

rn <- radialNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9)
onRender(rn, "function(el, x) { d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseover', null); }")

dn <- diagonalNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9)
onRender(dn, "function(el, x) { d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseover', null); }")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

It is working for the force network. 

However, although the other network types also habe nodes, there is not change at all.

Comment: Each plot type has unique options and underlying JavaScript. Make your question more specific.

Comment: Ok, I see.
I want to run the appropriate onRender-Statement on radialNetwork and diagonal networks (see my 'answer below' for an example).

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for `diagonalNetwork()` and `radialNetwork()`